# Virus causing multiple explorer.exe instances using high memory

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, virus, anti-virus

To begin, yes, there are similar questions out there, even on this site. However, none of them seem to off a solution outside of format the computer.

Story time! (Or the background to this whole ordeal)

Pretty sure this one has been looming for at least a month, since it was about a month ago when I tried to update AVG 2014 -> 2015. It failed, and in the meantime I installed AdAware until I could mess with it more. The other day I finally realized after some help on AVG's forum that several things were missing, such as Windows Firewall. I finally found [this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5366225a-46e7-4d6c-a389-8bd18a5c3aad/windows-firewall-damaged-by-windows-7-antivirus-2012?forum=w7itprosecurity) which allowed me to get things going and AVG reinstalled. It did find a couple viruses, which were removed, but then I noticed that explorer had multiple instances running, some of which were near to well above 1,000,000 K memory usage. AVG hasn't found anything else. AdAware obviously didn't find anything, and MalwareByes didn't find anything either, though it is constantly blocking internet requests from explorer.exe. I even corrupted explorer.exe so that sfc could fix it, and still the issue persists.

I had a thought that perhaps a driver was to blame, based on a previous experience with the Google redirect virus, however, nothing looks **overly** suspicious in the device manager or in the drivers folder.

Any hints or suggestions are welcome. I'm really trying to avoid having to do a refresh on this computer, as reinstalling everything takes a good 10+ hours if things go well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future visitors, after spending probably around 5 hours trying to find some other way to not have to redo the computer, I eneded up redoing the computer. This was decided after using Avast which found that there was a rootkit issue in the MBR. If you have that, save some time and just reinstall windows.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to try would be, I guess:

1. Disconnect from internet.
2. Uninstall AVG and any other antiviruses you might have.
3. Install Avast! from a USB that you downloaded it to on another computer.
4. Run a scan and try to fix all problems that come up.

(Generally having multiple antiviruses is never a good thing, and does **not** make your computer safer. Also, being connected to the net with no antivirus, that's why we're switching if off)

**Alternatively, if you can:**

1. Remove hard drive from computer
2. Connect to working, trusted and protected computer.
3. Scan from there with antivirus of choice, and try to fix problems.

Comment: I removed MalewareBytes, disabled AVG, and tried Avast just to have it crash the computer mid-scan. The only thing it's found is something in the MBR, which it labels "Cidox:E [Rtk]" I also can't do the no-internet method since I'm working on this computer remotely. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, I guess going on checking other antiviruses would give the same results... Honestly, I'm clueless, this is a bad situation you're in. Are you able to do the "restore computer to previous point in time" thing?

Comment: No, I think the virus wiped out previous restore points. At this point, we just went ahead redid the computer. *groan* :)

Comment: Well I guess that was the only thing you could do. Well, watch out for virii in the future :)